# How long does a Bundle last?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, bundle, android-lifecycle

I know that a `Bundle` can be used to pass data between activities, as well as for saving and restoring data in cases of configuration changes like a screen rotation.

I also read that `SharedPreferences` is the preferred way to store persistent data, rather than a `Bundle`.

Why exactly is this the case? In order for a `Bundle` to handle a configuration change, it would have to persist even after an activity is destroyed. So what exactly is the lifespan of a `Bundle`? Is there a certain point where it arbitrarily gets eliminated by garbage collection, or does a `Bundle`'s data persist for as long as you don't manually choose to clear it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bundle` lasts while the Activity exists, aka it has not been finished.

An interesting fact to note is that when *process death* occurs and Android massacres your application and the Application class is recreated (`onCreate()` is called), then the Activity stack is reconstructed, and the activity is reinitialized from the `saveInstanceState` bundle.

The `SharedPreferences` literally stores the data you give it in an XML file in the `data/<applicationname>/preferences` folder, if I remember the location right.

Comment: When is an activity considered finished? I know it's not when the activity is destroyed. Also it seems that when the user presses back to exit an app, the bundle gets reset? So would it be correct to say that an activity is finished when the user manually exits an app?

Comment: An activity is **finished** if you either force stop the app, or the user presses the `Back` button, and the activity `onBackPressed()` implementation calls `finish()` method. You can access whether an activity is finishing in your `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` methods using `isFinishing()` method.

Comment: For further and clear enough information see [Options for preserving UI state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options).

Answer (score 2):

[**SharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) are for simple persistent settings storage. Like the home page on a Browser that should be available every time the user opens the app. These are just key:value pairs designed to hold simple things.

[**Bundle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) is a way of storing data to either pass to another Context (another Activity, Service, etc) or to save and restore your own current state in onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstance state. This data is **NOT** persistent and used while the application is in use.

Comment: But if Bundle can be used to restore during onRestoreInstance, it had to persist past an activity's onDestroy, right? So wouldn't the data be considered persistent?

Comment: As long as the application is running. Once the application is destroyed so is the bundle data.

Comment: @Shahzeb "Once the application is destroyed so is the bundle data" - only if you mean the user finishing the application. Saved instance state (bundle data) survives system-initiated process death [Source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options)